# Difference between JSP and WEBSTART

Tags: java, jsp, java-web-start

Friends, Previously I have worked with **EJB-WEBSTART CLIENT** project, and Now i have joined with project using **JSP**.
I could understand *WEBSTART*, which is an implementation of *JNLP* and will be responsible for downloading client jars.
But Why we need JSP?
Why TWO different technology?
Which is best at what environment?
IS it both work together?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webstart is used to download and execute a fat Java application on client machines.

JSPs are used to build web applications, generating HTML pages and running in the browser.

Would you like to have to download a 5MBs jar file to use Google, Amazon, EBay, Facebook or whatever webapp? If not, then don't use WebStart to develop this kind of application.

Comment: If HTML is using animation or size of the HTML page is about to 5MBs still JSP can be handle this?

Comment: JSP can generate whatever you want, included a 5MBs page. But this would lead to a horrible user experience. You generate whatever text you want with JSP. If this text happens to be animated-HTML code, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because someone prefers apples than pears.

`Webstart` will start a Java application within a JRE at clientside. (JAR-Files are transferred to the client)

`JSP` will render HTML-pages that will be displayed within a webbrowser. (HTML-files will be transferred to the client)

These are completely different technologiestacks.